# Autostart Play2 application on run from console

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

When I am typing 'start' in play console, my application is starting immediately.
When I am using 'run' command, I need to refresh the web page for that, is there any way to avoid this behavior?
I have some code in Global class, and I would like to run it on 'run' command.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you are looking for.

What I understand:

- when you call `start`, your project is compiled and only then the application starts;
- when you call `run`, your application is compiled on the first call from browser.

To avoid the compilation time on the first access, just run `compile` before `run` and you will have the same behavior.

Comment: Not really, Global class is not called immediately after compile and run, I still need to refresh page in browser.